# Couldn't load file: Pictures/Saved Pictures/AA16.png - tsx file problem

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I made a tilemap using Tiled, and I copy pasted both it and its tsx file into android assets, but for some reason the thing can't load the png files in my tsx file.

Here is the code I have to render the thing:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private GenericGame game;
    private OrthographicCamera gamecam;
    private Viewport gamePort;
    private Hud hud;
    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthoCachedTiledMapRenderer renderer;




public PlayScreen(GenericGame game){
    this.game = game;
    gamecam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new FitViewport(GenericGame.V_WIDTH, GenericGame.V_HEIGHT, gamecam);
    hud = new Hud(game.batch);


    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();


    //Put The tiledmap in here vib.
    map = mapLoader.load("Generic Map Box 2.tmx");

            renderer = new OrthoCachedTiledMapRenderer(map);
    gamecam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2,0 );


}

    @Override
    public void show() {

    }
    public void HandleInput(float dt){
if(Gdx.input.isTouched())
    gamecam.position.x += 100 *dt;


    }


public void update(float dt){
    HandleInput(dt);

    gamecam.update();
    renderer.setView(gamecam);

}
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);

    // makes screen black
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gamePort.update(width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

It should have shown my tiledmap in the window, but it just cant load any of the tiles for the tileset.